# No need for HTTPS at all, but there seems to be no other way from the web browser

Tags: http, browser, https, ssl-certificate

Given a web application running over an HTTPS connection. It also has to communicate with a Java application on the local area network.

This server is literally in the same room with the PC on which the web app is running, a simple HTTP connection would be completely fine between the two, but since the web app is running over HTTPS, the browser forces the HTTPS.

It's already stupid and a big overkill that I must employ an HTTPS server in the Java application just because of that, but still now it doesn't work yet, because now the browser is complaining about the certificate that it is self-signed..

I mean, do I really need to purchase an SSL certificate so two of my computers in the same room can communicate over HTTP? Even if I wanted I couldn't. There's not even a fix domain.

I'm confused, is there a way around?

---

**UPDATE:**

The web application is served from the Internet, that's why the HTTPS connection. Whereas it should receive data from a Java application running locally. Hundreds of megabytes in every couple of minutes (confidential medical images) so sending all that through a proxy is not really an option.

I also wanted to avoid the need of any manual configuration from the user's side to make the communication work (like importing a certificate into the web browser and similar) but maybe I have no other option.

Comment: You can import the self signed certificate into your browsers certificate cache, then it will get accepted.

Comment: Or you could place a reverse proxy between your browser and that web application.

Comment: If I don't want to mess with proxies and any manual configuration like setting up firewall rules, adding certificates to the browser... could WebSocket be a solution? Something that works out of the box?

Comment: Certainly not a WebSocket, I do not see how that should work or how that should save you from having to implement something. If the web application is locally based on some standard http server (apache or whatever) then you can configure a reverse proxy in there. That most likely is the easiest approach if you (why ever) do not want to once manually import the certificate.

Comment: Mentioning WebSocket was stupid, I forgot it also had to be WSS that needs a certificate just as well. I updated the question.

Comment: Originally you said that this web server "is literally in the same room" as the app, whatever software that is. Now in the update you state that the web application is served "from the internet". How should we understand those two statements? If "from the internet" means via a routeable IP address, so via an external network, then _certainly_ you do not want to skip encryption.

Comment: Consider it as a regular website like stackoverflow or youtube or any other served from the internet over https. You open it in a web browser running on a computer located in a room of a building. In this same room on the same LAN network on which this computer is, there is another computer with a Java application. It has an [http server](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) the web application should get data from. And this is what seems to be impossible to accomplish thanks to the web browser.

Comment: Why don't you sketch that in the question? That is a completely different situation. In that case there is indeed no way around using https, unless you can change the web application itself. Reason is the builtin browser protection against encryption breaching. They are absolutely stickt in that they block all attempts to access a non encrypted resource from within an encrypted situation. There (fortunately) is no way around that limitation. There are very good reasons behind that.

Comment: A simple reverse proxy is trivial to set up and will work in this scenario. It is a few lines of configuration in a standard http server like apache, for example.

Comment: I can change the web application, the java application, the server of the web application, anything. Thanks for helping me so long and sorry for extending this conversation that far in the comments section, but I still don't see how I could solve the problem with a reverse proxy. Can you please provide a link to some description/tutorial/documentation or an answer maybe where I could learn more?

Comment: You actually face the "same origin policy" modern browsers follow for very good reasons. If you can change the way that web application is delivered, then read about setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` http header. It allows to whitelist specific URLs the client side logic is allowed to make requests to that would normally be blocked according to the "same origin policy". The technology behind that is called "cross site resource sharing" (CORS). I _think_ it allows to whitelist a http url from within a https framework, but you will have to check that.